# MailMerge if-statement with dynamic table inside

Tags: c#, ms-word, mailmerge, aspose, aspose.words

I'm currently working on a MailMerge Word-docx. When we had the following, everything worked fine:
[image]

And the result was:
[image]

---

What we want is to not show this table if there aren't any Authorization-events, so I've changed it to the following:
[image]

With the following result:
[image]

As you can see, the table is now empty, even though there are AuthorizationEvents. Is it possible to somehow use a dynamic table inside an `IF-MERGEFIELD`? Is this is a bug in Aspose's MailMerging, or I'm simply doing something wrong?

PS: I know the MailMerge-synthax we use with the `{{Something}}` is less known than the `<<Something>>`, but they work the same. Just a heads-up since I had questions regarding the MailMerge-synthax in the past.

---

Here is the .NET code (although I doubt it's relevant for my issue):

```
public class PrintDto
{
    public PrintDto(OurObject ourObject, ProcessTimeline processTimeline)
    {
        ...

        AutorisatieEvents = GetAutorisatieEvents(processTimeline);
        HeeftAutorisatieEvents = AutorisatieEvents.Any();
    }

    ...

    public IList<AutorisatieEventDto> AutorisatieEvents { get; private set; }
    public bool HeeftAutorisatieEvents { get; private set; }
}
```

AutorisatieEventDto:

```
public class AutorisatieEventDto
{
    public string Happened { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }
    public string Performer { get; set; }
    public string Opmerking { get; set; }
}
```

MailMerging code:

```
public byte[] GenerateDocument(Stream template, DocumentDataSource dataSource)
{
    var doc = new Document(template);

    doc.MailMerge.UseNonMergeFields = true;
    doc.MailMerge.CleanupOptions = MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveContainingFields |
                                   MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveUnusedFields |
                                   MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveUnusedRegions |
                                    MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveEmptyParagraphs;
doc.ResourceLoadingCallback = new ImageLoadingHandler();

// Support html MailMerge-fields
doc.MailMerge.FieldMergingCallback = new HandleMergeFieldInsertHtml();

doc.MailMerge.Execute(dataSource);
doc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions((IMailMergeDataSourceRoot) dataSource);

doc.UpdateFields();

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    doc.Save(memoryStream, SaveFormat.Pdf);
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Which is used in:

```
public byte[] CreatePrintAsBytes(PrintDto printData)
{
    if (printData == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("printData");

    var path = Path.Combine(_templatePath, "printdto.docx");

    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        var dataSource = new DocumentDataSource(printData);
        return DocumentConverter.GenerateDocument(fileStream, dataSource);
    }
}
```

And displayed like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Print(Guid id)
{
    var ourObject = NhSession.GetByGuid<OurObject>(id);
    var processTimeline = GetProcessTimelineOfOurObject(ourObject);
    var printData = new PrintDto(ourObject, processTimeline);

    var documentAsByteArray = _documentService.CreatePrintAsBytes(printData);

    return File(documentAsByteArray, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: This can only work if the code that's "filling" the mergefields is "seeing" the mergefields that are nested in the IF field. You may *think* what's happening is the equivalent to Word's "mail merge" but I'm fairly sure that, under the covers, it's not. For this reason, the ms-word and mail merge tags on this question should be removed as the problem is purely at the Aspose level. Whether this can work depends on whether the Aspose functionality is looking at Word's field codes when it searches for its "mail merge" tags. And you need to ask Aspose how to handle the conditional you want to use.

Comment: Please download test project from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75404275/TestProj.zip). The ~/TestPro/bin/Debug directory contains sample input/output documents. Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @AwaisHafeez That test project is looking good, thanks. It does mean we have to change a few of our generic methods, since we now use `doc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions((IMailMergeDataSourceRoot) dataSource);` to handle Regions, instead of setting the Columns and such of the DataSource manually. Today I'm a bit too occupied with other things, but I'll post back next week when I have time to implement your used techniques of the linked test-project.